# Synthesized NSNumber "out of scope"

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, synthesize

I'm doing an iOS app that crawl my youtube subscription's videos.
I have a problem when I want to navigate to see the next videos at the third time.

for these, I need to collect the start-index (NSNumber *youtubeStart) to add it the number of videos displayed (int const maxVideos).

For that, I have in my VideosViewController.h

```
@interface VideosViewController : UIViewController {
    NSNumber *youtubeStart;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *youtubeStart;
```

Then in VideosViewController.m

```
@synthesize youtubeStart;
static int const maxVideos = 6;
```

And a method that do

```
- (void) navigateVideos:(id)sender
{
    int navigate = 0;
    int start = [youtubeStart intValue];

    if(sender == bt_prev)
    {
        if(start >= maxVideos)
        {
            start -= maxVideos;
            navigate = 1;
        }
    }

    if(sender == bt_next)
    {
        start += maxVideos;
        navigate = 1;
    }

    if (navigate > 0)
    {   
        youtubeStart = [NSNumber numberWithInt:start];
        NSString *url = [NSString
             stringWithFormat:@"%@&start-index=%i&max-results=%i"
             , myUrl, [youtubeStart intValue], maxVideos];
        [self LoadOAuthUrl:url];
    }
}
```

When I "TouchUpInside" one of the buttons "bt_prev" or "bt_next" it call "navigateVideos".
I can press bt_prev or bt_next as many times as I want and it works but if I press bt_next 3 times in a row, youtubeStart become out of scope. It seems to not be able to go further than the third page.

Could you help me to understand why and how to handle it.

My others synthesized variables are not out of scope.

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I run the application on the ipad simulator from x-code. The application just crash with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. youtubeStart appear to be "out of scope" in the debugger just before "int start = [youtubeStart intValue];" and that's why it crash. When it works fine, youtubeStart is not out of scope.

EDIT 2:
The stacktrace is always missing.
I just got this in the debugger console:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

And this in the debugger with a red arrow:

```
0x0134d0b0  <+0036>  cmp    ecx,DWORD PTR [eax]
```

Comment: How in the world can a variable go out of scope at runtime depending on user input?

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by "out of scope"?  Is this returned from the webserver?

Comment: I run the application on the ipad simulator from x-code. The application just crash with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. youtubeStart appear to be "out of scope" in the debugger just before "int start = [youtubeStart intValue];" and that's why it crash. When it works fine, youtubeStart is not out of scope.

Comment: Nah, it's not out of the scope.  Please update your question with the stacktrace produced by the crash.

Comment: We cannot help without the stacktrace. It's likely from your `LoadOAuthUrl` method.

Comment: LoadOAuthUrl method is the use of gtm-oauth2 http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction. youtubeStart is not used anywhere else in the code. It is when I try to recover the value of youtubeStart that the application crash. For me it looks like youtubeStart as been release but i don't see where.

Comment: LoadOAuthUrl don't change the view but only some elements on the interface so viewDidUnload and dealloc are not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by you not using properties properly. You should always use `self.youtubeStart` when you assign a new value to the `youtubeStart` property. This is so that the object can be retained by your property. When you just assign directly to the iVar the actual `NSNumber` object is not retained, which means by the time you access it later (like when you call `start = [youtubeStart intValue]`) the object may have been auto-released.

I'm guessing that the 'out of scope' error really means that the object has been deallocated.

Here's what I would recommend...

Remove this code at the `@interface` in VideosViewController.h:

```
{
    NSNumber *youtubeStart;
}
```

And change your `@synthesize` to this:

```
@synthesize youtubeStart = _youtubeStart;
```

Then you will get some compiler errors/warnings where you directly access `youtubeStart` from within your code. Fix these by changing the access to `self.youtubeStart`.

This is a really good practice for using properties because it makes sure you don't ever accidentally use the iVar directly. If you do want to use the iVar directly, you can use `_youtubeStart` (this iVar is created automatically by the `@synthesize` line). However I recommend not using it at all unless you fully understand how the accessors and retain etc. works.

Also, if you struggle with this stuff I highly recommend looking into ARC :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. It works fine now and I understand why it was crashing. What is ARC? :) I'm new in objective-c development so i surely need to look at that.

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting - it means you don't worry about retain/release/autorelease, the compiler does it all for you. Look it up :)

Answer (score 0):

You failed to comply with Cocoa memory management rule. Your correct code should be

```
self.youtubeStart = [NSNumber numberWithInt:start];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine this way. Do i need to always use "self." to my synthesize variables ?

Comment: Auto-reply : YES! Always using self.name_of_the_var